# convert timestamp in ms to localtime

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

how to convert a ms timestamp to sek.

```
var timestamp_ms = 1599051221000
```

how can I convert this timestamp_ms to get DD:MM:YYYY - HH:MM:SS

I tried `new Date(timestamp_ms)` but it didn't work.

Comment: check out [date_fns](https://date-fns.org/)

Comment: I tried new Date(1599051220913).toLocaleString() but I still receive invalid date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve it [moment js](https://momentjs.com/) is a best library among all to play with date and time.

You should try that.

```
var timestamp_ms = 1599051221000

moment(timestamp_ms).format('DD:MM:YYYY - HH:MM:SS');
```

OR without any library simple JS

You are already a half way through `new Date(timestamp_ms)` all you need to store the response in a date variable and play around with [JS date docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

```
var timestamp_ms = 1599051221000

var date = new Date(timestamp_ms)

// date.getHours()
// date.getMinutes()
// date.getSeconds()
// ..... find further date methods in above linked js date docs.
```

Comment: Great, I installed this and works fine! Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Without additional librarys just pure JavaScript.

```js
var timestamp_ms = 1599051221000
var date = new Date(timestamp_ms);

let result = ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2) + ':' +  ('0' + (date.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + ':' +  date.getFullYear() + ' ' + ('0' + date.getHours()).slice(-2) + ':' + ('0' + date.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ':' +  ('0' + date.getSeconds()).slice(-2);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: what kind of datatype is timestamp_ms? in my case i declared it as date and the result is aN:aN:NaN aN:aN:aN

Comment: It's of type number. I just take it over from your question: `var timestamp_ms = 1599051221000`.